# Is there a chance this task (kata on codewars) can be performed as Declarative Programming?

Tags: java, regex

Recently I decided to buy regex cookbook by Jan Goyvaerts and Steven Levithan and learn it, because I am a Java beginner and regex is complete hell for me.
To gain some practice I took a task which is tagged as "Declarative Programming" and "Regular Expressions" on Codewars:

> Write a function, that takes in a string and replaces all the vowels
>   [a,e,i,o,u] with their respective positions within that string.

6 to 8 hours of reading the book and trying to achieve result led to nowhere, so I unlocked public solutions. Guess what I found? Most voted solutions were plain and simple

```
for i=0 to str.length-1
if the letter with index i is vowel, replace it
```

Is that "Declarative Programming" and "Regex"?

> In computer science, declarative programming is a programming
>   paradigm—a style of building the structure and elements of computer
>   programs—that expresses the logic of a computation without describing
>   its control flow. (Wiki)

Did I overlook something? I tried Pattern, Matcher and regex but, due to lack of experience, nothing came out, mostly because `indexOf()` can't take a regex as a parameter which is `"(?i)[aeiou]"`.
[Link to the task on Codewars, if needed](https://www.codewars.com/kata/the-old-switcheroo/java)

UPDATE: Probably even "(?i)[aeiou]{1}" or something..

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Comment: @vlad324 Exactly, might be those tags got me confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be the regex solution with a loop:

```
static String unvowel(String s) {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?i)[aeiou]").matcher(s);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (m.find()) {
        m.appendReplacement(sb, String.valueOf(m.start()));
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

It needs to create a copy, in order to have the correct positions.

In newer java, with lambdas:

```
static String unvowel(String s) {
    return s.replaceAll("(?i)[aeiou]", mr -> String.valueOf(mr.start()));
}
```

***I erred it seems, String still has no lambda replaceAll.*** Hence:

```
static String unvowel(String s) {
    return Pattern.compile("(?i)[aeiou]").matcher(s)
        .replaceAll("(?i)[aeiou]", mr -> String.valueOf(mr.start()));
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you very much, wasn't something obvious for a beginner, but definitely something to learn from.

Comment: I am still learning lambda, may I ask you why IDEA is complaining about `Cannot resolve method start()`?

Comment: @Shved if it helped you upvote and select it as correct answer this is how this community works.

Comment: I think `String.replaceAll` (still) has no lambda version of replaceAll. Added code that should work. The lambda version is **functional** telling what do do for each vowel. I would already call this **declarative**, as it is a _specification_, not only a _procedural_ recipe: replace the vowels with their start position.

Comment: @JoopEggen Thank you, yes I see it as declarative, though my Intellij is still whining about the replaceAll and start() methods. I am trying to comprehend the whole solution, so it's not big a deal.

Comment: Since [java 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.util.function.Function) a lambda should work in replaceAll.